# when I try to insert two records only one record is getting updated in CUR_STOCK table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreach

When I tried to insert two records to the REGULAR_SUPPY_DET table I am able to insert them but at the same time it should be updated in the CUR_STOCK table but only one record is getting updated in CUR_STOCK.

```
elseif ($_POST['action_type'] == 'add')
            {include 'dbconfig.php';
                $item_type=$_POST['item_type'];
                $exist_qty=$_POST['exist_qty'];
                $sup_qty=$_POST['sup_qty'];
                $sup_date=$_POST['sup_date'];
                $sql1="INSERT INTO REGULAR_SUPPLY_HDR(REQ_DATE) VALUES('$sup_date')";
                $res1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT MAX(REG_SUPPLY_REQ_ID) AS id  FROM REGULAR_SUPPLY_HDR");
                    $res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                       $sd=$res['id'];


                $i=0;
                foreach($item_type as $s_id)
                {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO REGULAR_SUPPLY_DET(REG_SUPPLY_REQ_ID,ITEM_ID, EXIST_ITEM_QUANTITY, SUPPLIED_QUANTITY, SUPPLIED_DATE) VALUES('$sd','$s_id', '".$exist_qty[$i]."', '".$sup_qty[$i]."', '$sup_date')";
                $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                $sql2="UPDATE CUR_STOCK SET QTY= QTY-$sup_qty[$i] WHERE ITEM_ID='$s_id'";
                $res1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
                $i++;
                }
                     echo 'ok';
            }
```

Comment: Can you add a tag for language or environment? (My guess: SQL?)

Comment: Thanks benc. I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

The php code *reads* like it will perform two updates on the second table if it performs two inserts on the first table. That makes me suspect that one of the `UPDATES` is failing silently, which I just discovered is the default behaviour of mysqli. You need to collect more information. You could start by displaying/posting to errorlog the value of `$res1`, `mysqli_query()` returns **FALSE** on failure. You may find [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) informative/useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DinoCoderSaurus.  I found out the mistake.  I have used res1 twice in the same function.